# Unable to resolve 355.0: missing requirement [355.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel-servlet)

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse

I am getting the following error when I try to start the process in the fuse server but the bundle has installed correctly.

```
Unable to resolve 355.0: missing requirement [355.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel-servlet)
```

I have injected the following dependency in the POM.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I also have included in the blueprind.xml file the following: `

```
<reference id="httpService" interface="org.osgi.service.http.HttpService"/>
<bean
    class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet" id="camelServlet"/>
<bean
    class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.osgi.OsgiServletRegisterer"
    destroy-method="unregister" id="registerCamel" init-method="register">
    <property name="alias" value="/restweb"/>
    <property name="httpService" ref="httpService"/>
    <property name="servlet" ref="camelServlet"/>
    <property name="servletName" value="CamelServlet"/>
</bean>
```

inside the camelContext I have the following:

```
<propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:properties.sql"/>
    <restConfiguration bindingMode="json" component="servlet"
        contextPath="/restweb" host="localhost" port="9999">
        <dataFormatProperty key="prettyPrint" value="true"/>
    </restConfiguration>
```

I am using Jboss version 10xx and runtime Jboss fuse 6.3. it is a rest web service, using bluprint route config. Is there anyone out there who can help me how to resolve this issue please?

Thanks in advance.

Hi Rugna, thanks for your reply. I have tried to install with features:install camel-servlet  **** and using this command I get the following error thrown but I do not know how to resolve the issue and install features I wanted.

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:list | grep camel-servlet
[uninstalled] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-servlet                           camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[uninstalled] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-servletlistener                   camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:install camel-servlet
Error executing command: The container is managed by fabric, please use fabric:profile-edit --feature camel-servlet/0.0.0 target-profile instead. See fabric:profile-edit --help for more information.
JBossFuse:karaf@root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bundle requires `camel-servlet` artifact, which is not available by default in JBoss Fuse 6.3.0.

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:list | grep camel-servlet
[uninstalled] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-servlet                                 camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[uninstalled] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-servletlistener                         camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
```

Install it using

```
features:install camel-servlet
features:install camel-servletlistener
```

Then verify the availabily of camel servlet packages:

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> exports | grep servlet
...
303 org.apache.camel.component.servlet; version=2.17.0.redhat-630187
303 org.apache.camel.component.servlet.osgi; version=2.17.0.redhat-630187
304 org.apache.camel.component.servletlistener; version=2.17.0.redhat-630187
```

Then please verify how your bundle is built, because the required package for Camel servlet is `org.apache.camel.component.servlet` not `org.apache.camel-servlet`.

---

if you package using maven-bundle-plugin and manually declare the dependency, your POM should look like the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            ...
            <Import-Package>
                org.apache.camel.component.servlet;version="[2.17,2)",  // package name here
                *
            </Import-Package>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hi Rugna, thanks for your reply. I have tried to install with features:install camel-servlet  **** and using this command I get the following error thrown but I do not know how to resolve the issue and install features I wanted.

Comment: JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:list | grep camel-servlet
[uninstalled] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-servlet                           camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[uninstalled] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-servletlistener                   camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:install camel-servlet
Error executing command: The container is managed by fabric, please use fabric:profile-edit --feature camel-servlet/0.0.0 target-profile instead. See fabric:profile-edit --help for more information.
JBossFuse:karaf@root>